# Apache Camel - How to configure endpoint with attributes in java

Tags: java, apache-camel, amq

Here is my perfectly working Camel route in XML below

```
<route id="someId">
            <from id="_from" uri="{{consumer.serviceName}}:queue:{{consumer.notificationQueue}}?{{consumer.queryParams}}"/>
            <log loggerRef="loggerId" message="Messages throttling from Queue"/>
            <throttle prop:timePeriodMillis="{{throttle.timePeriod}}">
                <constant>{{throttle.maximumRequestsPerSecond}}</constant>
                <log loggerRef="logger" message="Consuming notification message from Queue {{consumer.myQueue}} : ${body}"/> 
                <bean id="beanId" method="process" ref="MyProcessor"/>
            </throttle>
        </route>
```

Now, I want to write a similar camel endpoint in Java.
Can you please tell me how to add log and throttle attributes in it?

```
MyProcessor  messageProcessor;
String Uri = serviceName + ":queue:" + queueName + "?" + queryParams;
Endpoint ep = camelContext.getEndpoint(Uri);
Consumer consumer = ep.createConsumer(messageProcessor);
consumer.start();
```

Comment: You mean migrate your xml route to java dsl style ?

Comment: Yes, kind of. Actually, the other module's code is written using Java DSL, so I want to use Java there instead of refactoring the entire module in XML

Comment: Is this some production code or code used for testing? Camel provides an [adviceWith](http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html) construct where you can alter your route at runtime. This feature is maily used for testing Camel stuff, at least I haven't tried it yet on production code but you might give it a shot. If you are really courious you might check what weaving routes does behind the scenes and then do it within your code

Comment: This is unexpected, @Bhuvan. I'm sure you will be able to do it with patience, but I don't think you will find much help. As you are familiar, Camel supports several approaches for defining routes, but what you are trying is not one of them. With due respect, your approach makes me think you are unwilling to learn how to use Camel as it is intended to be used and would rather force it to fit your expectations.

Comment: @DavidS I understand, but I don't want to modify the already written framework code running in production.

Comment: Oh, I see the problem, @Bhuvan. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will help you:

```
 from("{{consumer.serviceName}}:queue:{{consumer.notificationQueue}}?{{consumer.queryParams}}").id("from_")
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, loggerObject, "Messages throttling from Queue")
            .throttle(constant("{{maximumRequestsPerSecond}}")).timePeriodMillis(1000)//pass throttle.timePeriod parameter from your config here
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, loggerObject, "Consuming notification message from Queue {{consumer.myQueue}} : ${body}")
            .bean(beanObject, "process").id("beanId")
            .end();
```

Comment: No. Please check my question, I have the java code already written. I have to modify to add throttle property in it

Comment: I asked you about migrate. You said yes. I gave you java camel route created according to [guide](http://camel.apache.org/java-dsl.html) with "log and throttle attributes" as u asked (as in XML route in question). Second part of code in question doesn't looks like route builder. It's not entirely clear what you want.

Comment: The java code written in my question is already working. I have to find a way to add "throttle" attribute in it (like the way I have added in XML)

Comment: Of course it's working cause you create Consumer and start consuming.It's equivalent of route with 2 endpoints (from -> to processor). Now you want more endpoints and still don't want to use route builder.  Any time you can create Throttler as processor and LogProducer from LogEndpont  and build route using this 4 objects manually setting them in each other in turn, but it is insane way.

Comment: Can you please modify your answer to add the code sample that you are suggesting? I am relatively new to Camel and finding it difficult to understand your approach.

Comment: My words about manually building route using endpoint's object was hasty. There is a lot of clever and complicated code behind xml route in your question or java dsl route in my answer. You can't simply reproduce it manually. Throttle and log is not "attributes" it is route definitions that should be added to your route. You should look camel [guide](http://camel.apache.org/java-dsl.html) how route builder works. Migrated route from XML style to Java DSL style i already gave you.